# How to connect on two port numbers with at least two sockets in order to send text messages and transfer files (multithreaded java)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to create a program that is able to send and recieve text messages/files between a client and a server.

There are three classes (main function file, server file, client file)

Command line arguments to run server:

```
java MainThread -l 3000
```

Command line arguments to run client:

```
java MainThread -l 4021 -p 3000
```

The "3000" port number will be the  text messaging socket port.

The "4021" port number will be the file Transferring socket port.

Notice how "4021" is not present on the command line arguments for the server---would this make it impossible to connect on two different ports where one port is for text messaging and the other is for file transferring?

Would it be possible for the server to connect to the client without the knowledge of "4021" until later in the program where the client could send "4021 to the client in a string or something?

Is there some way to get the file port number of the client without typing "4021" on the server command line arguments? If so, how?

When the program runs and connects, it outputs these options:

```
Enter an option ('m', 'f', 'x'): 

(M)essage (send)

(F)ile (request) 

e(X)it
```

When the user types "m", the program will use the text messaging socket with the port number 3000

When the user types "f", the program will use the file transfering socket with the port number 4021

Current server code (one port for text):

```
public class ServerThread
{
    private String[] serverArgs;
    public Socket socket;
    public boolean keepRunning = true;
    public int ConnectOnce = 0;
    public String option = "";
    public boolean isConnected = false;
    public String FILE_TO_SEND = "/Users/nanettegormley/Documents/workspace/assignment2/src/servers/cdm.jpg";

    public ServerThread(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        // set the instance variable

        this.serverArgs = args;
        if(ConnectOnce == 0)
        {
           //connecting for text messaging
            int port_number1 = Integer.valueOf(serverArgs[1]);
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number1);
            socket = serverSocket.accept(); 
            ConnectOnce = 4;
            isConnected = true;

        }
  }
```

For the code below I am using the same code as above, but changing/adding lines of new code to make it work separate port numbers so that file transferring and text messaging can operate on different ports.

Client code with two ports (one for text one for file Transfer)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class ClientThread implements Runnable
{
    int ConnectOnce = 0;
    public String[] clientArgs; // <-- added variable
    public static Socket socket;
    public Socket fileSocket;
    public boolean keepRunning = true;
    public String option = "";
    public String filePort = "";
    public ClientThread(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        // set the instance variable
        this.clientArgs = args;
        if(ConnectOnce == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                //would this be the right way to connect two separate ports, assuming the other side also has two separate ports as well?
                filePort = clientArgs[1];
                String port_number1= clientArgs[3];
                int normalPort = Integer.valueOf(port_number1);
                int filePortInt = Integer.valueOf(filePort);
                String host = "localhost";
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                socket = new Socket(address, normalPort);
                fileSocket = new Socket(address, filePortInt);
                ConnectOnce = 4;

            } 
            catch (UnknownHostException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Full working code (without file transfer) (don't have 10 reputation so can't post links)

dropbox.com/s/fcps9obgot2tbkr/WorkingText.zip?dl=0

Full current code (with two ports but got errors, does not work)

dropbox.com/s/5j5tbashvsfdl34/src.zip?dl=0

Screenshot of errors on current code (Client is top window, server is bottom window)

dropbox.com/s/49498m9n0mp1b7m/Screen%20Shot%202017-05-24%20at%2011.30.49%20AM.png?dl=0

My question is: If possible, how and when do you connect a client and a server using two separate port numbers (one for file transfer, one for text messaging)? Is the code I posted incorrect? If so, what changes should I make?

Comment: The client can send over a string with its address and port to the server. You can manually construct and open a socket on the server side based on that information, bypassing the stuff that ServerSocket would normally do for you.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you. Will the line "`fileTransferSocket = serverSocket.accept();` need to be executed on the server side after the line `socket = serverSocket.accept();` is already executed?

Comment: `fileTransferSocket = serverSocket.accept();` accepts a connection from any unknown client. It returns a Socket object opened to that client. I think you need to bypass that step and create the socket manually, because you need it to point to a very specific client. You can google any additional handshaking steps you'll need.

Comment: You need to read the FTP RFC. That's what you're implementing.